# JNI error occurrence with TestNG classpath setup

Tags: java, automated-tests, testng

I was looking at the TestNG documentation and I wanted to implement the DotTestListener class to override TestNG methods for logging and results (section 6.2.1 in the documentation)
https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

I'm trying to use this command in cmd to invoke the listener:

```
java -classpath C:\TestNG\plugins\testng7.0.jar;C:\eclipse-2018\Tests org.testng.TestNG -listener org.testng.reporters.DotTestListener testng.xml
```

note: I renamed the TestNG library myself to "testng7.0.jar"

\Tests is my eclipse project folder

When I run the command, I'm getting this exception in the CLI:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and
>   try again Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
>           at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           ... 7 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open cmd and cd into eclipse project directory, set the environment classpath as TestNG\plugins (all of the significant Jar libraries), path of selenium dependencies, and the path of the TestNG project bin folder containing the .class files:

```
java -classpath C:\eclipse-2018\Tests\bin;C:\Selenium_dependencies\*;C:\TestNG\plugins\* org.testng.TestNG -listener org.testng.reporters.DotTestListener testng.xml
```

the classpath may also be set this way:

1.

```
set classpath=C:\eclipse-2018\Tests\bin;C:\Selenium_dependencies\*;C:\TestNG\plugins\*
```

2.

```
java -classpath %classpath% org.testng.TestNG -listener org.testng.reporters.DotTestListener testng.xml
```

Selenium dependencies:

https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver/3.12.0/source-code